# Thick of a marker in ErrorListPlot

Tags: plotting

I have error bars that are too small, so the marker are too big, i want to shrink the dots.
If i do `ErrorListPlot[dato,PlotMarkers->{o,1}]` my bars do not show, but if i do `ErrorListPlot[dato,PlotStyle->Thin]` it draw the bars thin but the dot remains too big. What can i do?

Answer (score 4):

You can set a point size in `PlotStyle`:

```
ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 5}], PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[4]]
```

[image]

See belisarius's answer for full control using post-processing.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the point style like this:

```
SeedRandom[42];
ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 5}]] /. 
   Point[a__] :> {Red, PointSize[#], Point[a]} & /@ {.008, .1}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You could also make some concoction with `ErrorBarFunction[]`